# Delete Record in a File (C Programming)

Tags: c, file

I'm fairly new to C. At the moment, I'm learning about file management.
To further my understanding of files I wanted to create a Employee Database System, where the user can Create, Delete, Update or Retrieve an Employee Record.  First I created a struct which contains the employee's variables like ID, first name, last name and pay, then a function which creates the records, but the there is the problem. I know how to search from the file (using the ID number) but I don't know how to delete a particular record.

(I'm so sorry because I accidentally deleted my DeleteFunction so I cannot show that particular function in my code)

- My code does run well as far as I know, but you will find any errors

So here is my code:

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>

   typedef struct employee{
   int id;
   char name[40];
   float pay;
   }EMP;

  void CreateEmployee(struct employee [] );
  void DisplayRecord();

  int main() {
      EMP e[20];
      CreateEmployee(e);
      //return 0;
    DisplayRecord();
    return 0;
}


void CreateEmployee(struct employee x[]){
char choice ='y';
int i=0;

//EMP employee[20];


FILE *fp;
fp = fopen("employee.txt","a");
if (fp==NULL){
    printf("File not created");
}
while((choice == 'Y') || (choice =='y')){
    printf("Enter the employee's id:");
    scanf("%i",&x[i].id);
    fprintf(fp,"%i\t",x[i].id);

    printf("\nEnter the employee's name:");
    scanf("%s",x[i].name);
    fprintf(fp,"%s\t",x[i].name);

    printf("\nEnter the employee's pay:");
    scanf("%f",&x[i].pay);
    fprintf(fp,"%.2f\t\n",x[i].pay);

    printf("\nEnter another employee?\n");
    printf("Y - Yes     N - No:\n");

    scanf("\n%c",&choice);
     i++;
}

fclose(fp);

}

void DisplayRecord(){

EMP temp;

FILE *fp = fopen("employee.txt", "r");

if(fp != NULL)
{

    while( !feof(fp) )
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%i %s  %f", &temp.id, temp.name, &temp.pay);

        printf("%i %s %f\n",temp.id, temp.name, temp.pay);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    }
else
 {
    printf("An error occurred opening the file\n");
 }
}
```

I don't know how to use random access file as yet; that's why I'm using sequential access at the moment.

Comment: Did you consider using a relational database (e.g. [sqlite](http://sqlite.org/), [PostGresql](http://postgresql.org/); read some [SQL tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/)...) or some indexed file (e.g. [gdbm](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdbm/)...)? It probably is more convenient for your case.

Comment: As to deleting a record in a file, you'd probably overwrite it with a new record, or write null bytes over it, or something similar.  Files don't shrink normally (but in POSIX, there is [`truncate()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/truncate.html)).  With sequential operations, you probably copy from one file to another.  When that's the case, deletion occurs when you decide not to write the record out to the new file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete a record, you have several choices:

1. Prepare by having a `deleted` field in each record, and when reading records, skip those that have `deleted == true`. To actually delete a record, set its `deleted` flag to `true` and save it.
2. Read the data file and write all records to a temporary file, except the one you want to delete. Finally, rename the temporary file to `employees.txt`.
3. Switch to a real database for managing the records, since all the typical operations are fast and easy then.

By the way, you haven't said *why* you love C as a programming language. If it is because you can quickly get your things done, you will be disappointed as soon as your programs get a little larger, since you have to do the memory management and error handling explicitly in your code. And, C makes it very easy to shoot you in the foot (so your program crashes and just doesn't work), since it doesn't have built-in memory protection. Therefore, before totally falling in love with that language, look around a little bit too see whether you can find something better.

Comment: Thanks Roland but what about this?                                                   Let's say I want the user of this program to enter the ID of the file that it is going to be delete right so it is going to be like this:                                   1. The user  enters the ID                                                                          2. Use a WHILE loop to search the file alongside a fscanf                           3. An IF  and a CONTINUE statement  are used so that when the ID is scanned  the loop continues and does not save that record into an array of struct

Comment: then we store that data into a new file just like you said